# Webpack Dev Server Not Watching or Updating Files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So webpack isn't updating any changes I make or rebundling build.js with changes. Pretty frustrating issue. Not sure what the deal is. Could really use some help! Thanks! Code is below.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, "dev");
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, "output");

var config = {
  watch: true,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    DEV + "/App.jsx"
  ],
  output: {
    path: OUTPUT,
    filename: "build.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        include: DEV,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel"],
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^15.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

I ran `./node_modules/.bin/webpack` to get the initial build.

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try passing the `-w` in the command e.g `webpack -w`

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -w`

Comment: I tried that, it updates but now every time I save file a hot-update.js and hot-update.json are put into my output folder.

Comment: are those files located in your `dev` directory?

Comment: All my dev directory has is an App.jsx file. When I make changes to it, webpack is not recompiling my changes to build.js so whatever is being served to localhost:8080 is out of date and doesn't reflect any changes.

Comment: try removing the plugin parts of the config file 

`plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
`

Answer (score 0):

React-Hot-Loader can be very specific in its configuration.  I would try the [minimal successful configuration](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js) for React Hot Loader (taking care to use similar pathing and not via variable initialization with path.resolve) :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/App.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```